# New minimized ribbon in outlook 365

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-addins

I am working on a VSTO project which is almost done, but I cannot find any documentation about a specific thing.

The Addin has currently 1 big button (on the left) and 2 small ones (on the right) in the ribbon.

When the ribbon is put in "simplified mode" in Office 365, I want to make the 2 small disappear (it becomes a "1 line ribbon" so having 3 buttons takes too much space).
=> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-simplified-ribbon-44bef9c3-295d-4092-b7f0-f471fa629a98

Is is possible to detect the "minimization" and make the 2 buttons visible/invisible on the event ?

Otherwise maybe there is a configuration to say it is a "Secondary" button which becomes invisible in simplified mode ?

Thanks for any pointer

Answer (score 0):

I used a hook on registry value as there seem to be no other way to check this